# Teams Meetings created via the Microsoft graph API cannot be edited in the outlook

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, ms-office, microsoft-teams

We are using [this MS Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to create a calendar event. In the event body, we want to share the meeting join link for an existing team meeting. To do this, we patch the event body html using [this MS Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). It creates the event and everything works fine.

However, when we edit this event in the outlook calendar, we receive the following error.

[image]

Clicking OK on the above error prompt will let me open the event. However, when I change some things and click Send, the updates cannot be sent. An error appears as shown below.

[image]

Note: As reported by one of our customers, it started happening about four weeks ago that they could no longer edit these events in Outlook.

I am logged in with the same account in both my teams and outlook.

We've tried the following things to fix the issue, but it hasn't worked so far.

- Update Office
- Clean up the Teams Cache.
- Log out of Teams and Outlook and then log in again.
- Uninstall and reinstall Teams.

Other Info -

The team's version is 1.4.00.29469 (64-bit).

Microsoft Outlook for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2110 Build 16.0.14527.20270) 64-bit

Operating system: Windows 10 Pro Version: 21H1. OS Build - 19043.1348

Comment: We tried to repro this issue from our end, We are able to create that event using Graph API and also able to edit the event from outlook.
 resolved by a recent Office/Teams update.
Microsoft Teams Version 1.4.00.30066 (64-bit)